# Trying to run .exe with cmake and then make, but the access is denied and then the file disappears in Terminal using Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, makefile, terminal

I have to do one programming homework, where I have to complete a file *.cpp*. I have done it perfectly. When I want to execute using *cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"* and *make* in the Windows terminal, I get a *runhw02.exe* file which I run it in the terminal, but it shows the error: *"Access denied"* and then the file *runhw02.exe* disappears from the folder.

I do not understand this behaviour. I tried to run the terminal as an administrator, but by doing the *cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"*, I get this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.22000.978]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\pascu\Documents\c++\Examples C++\ex2

C:\Users\pascu\Documents\c++\Examples C++\ex2>cd build

C:\Users\pascu\Documents\c++\Examples C++\ex2\build>cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:842 (file):
  file STRINGS file "C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples
  C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:123 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:948 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (Permission denied):

    C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:123 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:951 (string):
  string begin index: 1 is out of range 0 - 0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:123 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:959 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " * 16 + ": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_TIMES (2).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:123 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:961 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (Permission denied):

    C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:123 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:1002 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (Permission denied):

    C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:123 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:842 (file):
  file STRINGS file "C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples
  C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:948 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (Permission denied):

    C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:951 (string):
  string begin index: 1 is out of range 0 - 0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:959 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " * 16 + ": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_TIMES (2).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:961 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (Permission denied):

    C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:11 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_CHECK)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Users/pascu/Downloads/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.24.2-windows-x86_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.2.0-mingw-w64ucrt-10.0.0-r1/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-11.2.0-mingw-w64ucrt-10.0.0-r1/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/pascu/Documents/c++/Examples C++/ex2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This is *CMakeLists.txt* file in case there is an error, but I guess no because everything seems quite well

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

project(hw02)

add_library(hw02 combinatorics.cpp)
target_include_directories(hw02 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(runhw02 run.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runhw02 PRIVATE hw02)
```

I do not know why I am getting an error in the terminal as an administrator, but I want to solve first the strange behavior of *runhw02.exe* file which the access is denied and disappears when I execute it .I followed all the instructions precisely to run the *.cpp* file in Windows, but I still have some problems.

Comment: Any chance you're running a virus scanner that could be disabled for this experiment?  In Windows, there's no way for an exe to delete itself, so something else is doing it.

Comment: Hmm could be. I am using Kaspersky, so I am going to disable it in case this is the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it was this problem!